# Bonificação não desconta no Limite diário de pontos?

Tags: debate, suporte, recompensa, reputação, pontos

Vou montar um cenário como exemplo, mas que realmente aconteceu de fato.

Imagine que eu recebi 20 votos favoráveis, isso me deixaria com 200 pontos de reputação o limite do dia. No entanto eu fui lá e abri uma Bonificação de 50 pontos, dessa forma foram removidos 50 pontos da minha reputação e fiquei novamente com 150 pontos no dia ok.

Sendo assim, eu acreditei que "perdendo" 50 pontos dos 200 e ficando apenas com 150 no dia eu poderia ganhar mais 50, pois ao meu ver eu estaria novamente dentro do limite dos 200 pontos diários.  Só que não foi bem assim...

Minha frustração é que quando um usuário delata a conta eu perco pontos, pontos referentes ao limite diário, podendo até ficar negativo no dia. Outro pondo é que se eu tenho 200 ponto e dou uma Bonificação é descontado imediatamente, e eu deixo de ganhar a medalha `Épico/Legendário`, pois não tenho os 200 diários!

**Então porque ao doar 50 pontos eu não posso continuar acumulando pontos no dia?** *Não achei isso muito justo por parte do sistema.*

---

Esse números acima não foram exatamente meu caso, mas aqui etá o **exemplo real**.

Ontem eu estava com 277 pontos, abri uma bonificação e meu saldo do dia caiu para 227 pontos, ao meu ver eu deveria poder ganhar outros 50 pontos já que saíram 50 pontos da minha conta no dia, assim como acontece quando algum usuário que votou em vc delata o perfil da rede, vc pede os pontos no dia...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém como podem ver na imagem, de nada adiantou, mesmo depois de perder 50 pontos oferecendo a bonificação eu continuei sem poder ganhar mais pontos no dia...

**OBS:** O curioso é que os pontos de `[tag]` eu recebi, só não recebi os pontos de reputação.

Comment: Parece que isso é *by design* mesmo: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231637/401803

Comment: @hkotsubo o link é interessante, mas parece que não tem algo realmente concreto de pq funciona dessa forma. O que eles falam é que os pontos de Bonificação são "separados" dos pontos de reputação, mas algumas pontas ficam abertas ainda...

Comment: É, tb achei as explicações incompletas... Mas foi o único link que achei :) E como é um feature request que foi recusado, parece que a SE achou melhor que deve continuar sendo assim mesmo...